# Check value in a List<Class> contains in any List<String> usingLambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a `List<Expenditure>`, in that one column is pptCd(String value). I have one more `List<String>` which has list of pptCds. I want to get all records in `List<Expenditure>` which has pptCd in the `List<String>` using lambda expression. any idea?

```
private IsValid(List<Expenditure> ExpnTrxs)
    {
        var pptCds = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ReferenceEnums.pptCds));

        var validpptCdsTrxs = AAExpnTrxs.FindAll(x => x.pptCd.);
        var inValidPpptCdsTrxs = AAExpnTrxs.FindAll(x => x.pptCd);

        ....................
        ....................
        ....................
    }
```

Comment: Which lambda expression you've tried already?

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
ExpnTrxs.Where(x => pptCds.Contains(x.pptCd)).ToList();
```